# What is the difference between Clojure's "send" and "send-off" functions with respect to dispatching an action to an agent?

Tags: clojure, agents

The Clojure API describes these two functions as:

> (send a f & args) - Dispatch an action to an agent. Returns the agent immediately. Subsequently, in a thread from a thread pool, the state of the agent will be set to the value of: (apply action-fn state-of-agent args)

and

> (send-off a f & args) - Dispatch a potentially blocking action to an agent. Returns the agent immediately. Subsequently, in a separate thread, the state of the agent will be set to the value of: (apply action-fn state-of-agent args)

The only obvious difference is **send-off** should be used when an action may block. Can somebody explain this difference in functionality in greater detail?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

all the actions that get sent to any agent using `send` are run in a thread pool with a couple of more threads than the physical number of processors. this causes them to run closer to the cpu's full capacity. if you make 1000 calls using `send` you don't really incur much switching overhead, the calls that can't be processed immediately just wait until a processor becomes available. **if they block then the thread pool can run dry.**

when you use `send-off`, a new thread is created for each call. if you `send-off` 1000 functions, the ones that can't be processed immediately still wait for the next available processor, but they may incur the extra overhead of starting a thread if the **send-off threadpool** happens to be running low.  **it's ok if the threads block** because each task (potentially) gets a dedicated thread.

Comment: send-off does not really create a new thread, it uses a different, expandable thread pool.

Comment: thanks: I'll edit to include that. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Seems to me that if you have enough additional resources and are doing things like IO where there is a lot of blocking, the send-off variant would be good, and if you are doing CPU intensive things, then the straight send variant would be more efficient?